# Change TabbedPage MainTitle Color, when user open by Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPage)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, tabs, xamarin.forms

So, I got this problem, and I don't know to solve.
Basically, I would like to change the TabLayout's mainTitle color, when i call from Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPage); Seems easy, but it isn't.
I don't know to change any property, of that top bar...
I see, a property, in a NavigationPage class called "BarTextColorProperty". What can I do with this?

I had tested, a same sample, but in another method... Navigation.PushModalAsync(tabbedPage), this time, in a modal page, and worked :)

But, I really need this work in a Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPage), because backButton.

To finish, I know, if you look the code, you see that Navigation.PushModalAsync(tabbedPage), the tabbedPage is inside a NavigationBar, and Works, but I try to put a tabbedPage inside a NavigationPage(in PushAsync method;) , and the Xamarin, draws 3 bars... The first bar, has only a back button...

Can someone help???
If, you need more code, tell me

Code: 
-> Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPage);

```
[button1.Clicked += (s, e) =>
        {
            tabbedPage.CurrentPageChanged += (a, b) =>
            {
                if (tabbedPage.CurrentPage.GetType().Equals(typeof(Page1)))
                {
                    tabbedPage.BarTextColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    tabbedPage.BarTextColor = Color.Orange;
                }
            };
            Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPage);
        };

-> Navigation.PushModalAsync(tabbedPage),

button2.Clicked += (s, e) =>
        {
            NavigationPage navigationPageTabbedPage = new NavigationPage(tabbedPage);
            tabbedPage.CurrentPageChanged += (a, b) =>
            {
                if (tabbedPage.CurrentPage.GetType().Equals(typeof(Page1)))
                {
                    navigationPageTabbedPage.BarTextColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    navigationPageTabbedPage.BarTextColor = Color.Orange;
                }
            };

            Navigation.PushModalAsync(navigationPageTabbedPage);
        };][1]
```

Comment: LINK IMAGES: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/97909b77b14d7b352a973be5f4689bc520170925231433/7797ef

Comment: Sorry, not quite understand, what is it to do with `NavigationPage`? You want to change `TabbedPage`'s bar's text color when any bar item is selected?

Comment: Thanks for reply :)... So, I would like to change TabbedPage's top bar title color, when user change tab (CurrentPageChanged event)... For instance, if tab1 is selected, title is green, if tab2 is selected, title is orange.. I try to do that, when tabbedPage open by "Navigation.PushAsync method" and didn't work... (button1) If I open by "Navigation.PushModalAsync method", it worked... (button2), but I don't want to open this by Navigation.PushModalAsync, because I need a backbutton... How can I do this, by Navigation.PushAsync, and get the same result that i have in Navigation.PushModalAsync??

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late responding, by double check your description and your code, I think you only want to change the title on the bar of the `TabbedPage` when current page is changed, then if your `TabbedPage` is something like this:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPageForms"
             x:Class="TabbedPageForms.MainPage">

    <local:TodayPage Title="Today"  />

    <local:SchedulePage Title="Schedule"  />
</TabbedPage>
```

You can simply implement this feature in its code behind for example like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        this.CurrentPageChanged += MainPage_CurrentPageChanged;
        ChangeBarColor();
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        this.CurrentPageChanged -= MainPage_CurrentPageChanged;
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }

    private void MainPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeBarColor();
    }

    private void ChangeBarColor()
    {
        var currentPage = this.CurrentPage;
        switch (currentPage.Title)
        {
            case "Today":
                this.BarTextColor = Color.Green;
                break;

            case "Schedule":
                this.BarTextColor = Color.Orange;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't see any problem relative to `NavigationPage`, you can show this `TabbedPage` with `NavigationPage` in App.cs just for example like this:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

[image]

Comment: Don't Worry :) It's Okayy :) Thanks for the reply, but I'm not looking for that... Have you seen my pictures? https://wetransfer.com/downloads/97909b77b14d7b352a973be5f4689bc520170925231433/7797ef

Comment: 1(2) and 2(2) pictures -> Navigation.PushAsync, I can't change "Tabbed Change Color Test" Color Title, when user change tab...

Comment: 3 and 4 pictures -> Navigation.PushModalAsync, there isn't problem here... But I want use "Navigation.PushAsync"... Thanks for suggestion "MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());", but I need to go back in Navigation...